# ZF3 Skeleton Application Vagrant - call with test.dev - how to configure

Tags: macos, vagrant, vagrantfile, zend-framework3

I installed the Skeleton Application of Zend Framework 3

```
composer create-project -n -sdev zendframework/skeleton-application ~/code
```

Then I started Vagrant into the application directory.

```
vagrant up
```

I dopend the website

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Everything works.
But now I want to call the website with the domain test.dev
Into /etc/hosts of my mac I can insert a line

```
127.0.0.1    test.dev
```

But this ist wrong into this case.

How can I realize it?
Do I have to change something into the Vagrant file?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to assign a static IP, you ca create a [private network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html#static-ip) and add the following line in your `Vagrantfile`

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.12"
```

now you can add this line in your host file

```
192.168.33.12    test.dev
```

and you will access your site directly on http://test.dev